# How to Restore Deleted AWS Hosted Zone Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I accidentally deleted my AWS hosted Zone which included deleting the ns and soa records.  I created a new hosted zone using my existing DNS name but discoverd that the name server (ns) DNS names were different.  I went to the registered domains section of AWS and got what I believe is the original ns DNS names.  I edited the new hosted zone ns records and replaced them with the registerd ns DNS names.  However I still cannot access my domain resources using my domain name.  Its only been an hour or so but still no luck.  I did a AWS CLI command "aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id /hostedzone/Z07300422FPN7YUXX4SDQ" found that the ns DNS names were different than the ones I edited.  So right now when I go to the AWS hosted zone and examine the ns DNS names they match the AWS registered domain ns DNS names.  However when I issue the AWS CLI command "aws route53 get-hosted-zone --id /hostedzone/Z07300422FPN7YUXX4SDQ" I get a different set of ns DNS names.  Is my proceedure correct?  Do I have to wait longer? Is their a better way?

Comment: Is there am AWS CLI command that can will get the origianal ns DNS names?  From there I can edit the new host ns record and hopefully get it working again.

Comment: Delete zone, create new one, add your records to the zone (do not modify NS records), go to registred domains and there modify ns records (use NS records from your newly created zone)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should contact [AWS Support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-contact-support.html).

---

The name servers (NS Records) are given to you by AWS when you create a Hosted Zone.

From the [Route53 Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/SOA-NSrecords.html)

> If you change the NS records, it doesn't change the name servers that Route 53 allocated. You cannot change the name servers that are associated with an existing hosted zone.

You can try [white-labeling the name servers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/white-label-name-servers.html) but it doesn't seem like these step will work if the hosted zone is deleted.